# problem while trying to implement a drag and drop direct upload with shrine direct_upload for aws rails 5.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, shrine, roda

**Code:**

**image_upload.js**

```
function uploadAttachment(attachment) {
  var file = attachment.file;
  var form = new FormData;
  form.append("Content-Type", file.type);
  form.append("forum_post_photo[image]", file);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open("POST", "/forum_post_photos.json", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", Rails.csrfToken());

  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event){
    var progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
    attachment.setUploadProgress(progress);
  }

  xhr.onload = function(){
    if (xhr.status == 201){
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      return attachment.setAttributes({
        url: data.image_url,
        href: data.image_url
      })
    }
  }

  return xhr.send(form);
}

document.addEventListener("trix-attachment-add", function(event){
  var attachment = event.attachment;

  if (attachment.file){
    console.log('new',attachment);
    return uploadAttachment(attachment);
  }
});
```

**shrine.rb**

```
require "shrine/storage/s3"

s3_options = {
  bucket:            Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket_name], # required
  access_key_id:     Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id],
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key],
  region:            Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket_region],
}

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache",upload_options: { acl: "public-read" } , **s3_options),
  store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "store",upload_options: { acl: "public-read" } ,**s3_options),
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :presign_endpoint, presign_options: -> (request) {
  filename = request.params["filename"]
  type     = request.params["type"]

  {
    content_disposition:    "inline; filename=\"#{filename}\"", # set download filename
    content_type:           type,                               # set content type (required if using DigitalOcean Spaces)
    content_length_range:   0..(10*1024*1024),                  # limit upload size to 10 MB
  }
}
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data
```

**trix-upload**

```
require "shrine/storage/s3"

s3_options = {
  bucket:            Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket_name], # required
  access_key_id:     Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id],
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key],
  region:            Rails.application.credentials.aws[:bucket_region],
}

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache",upload_options: { acl: "public-read" } , **s3_options),
  store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "store",upload_options: { acl: "public-read" } ,**s3_options),
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :presign_endpoint, presign_options: -> (request) {
  filename = request.params["filename"]
  type     = request.params["type"]

  {
    content_disposition:    "inline; filename=\"#{filename}\"", # set download filename
    content_type:           type,                               # set content type (required if using DigitalOcean Spaces)
    content_length_range:   0..(10*1024*1024),                  # limit upload size to 10 MB
  }
}
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data
 trix-upload
function uploadAttachment(attachment) {
  var file = attachment.file;
  var form = new FormData;
  form.append("Content-Type", file.type);
  form.append("forum_post_photo[image]", file);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open("POST", "/forum_post_photos.json", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", Rails.csrfToken());

  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event){
    var progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
    attachment.setUploadProgress(progress);
  }

  xhr.onload = function(){
    if (xhr.status == 201){
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      return attachment.setAttributes({
        url: data.image_url,
        href: data.image_url
      })
    }
  }

  return xhr.send(form);
}

document.addEventListener("trix-attachment-add", function(event){
  var attachment = event.attachment;

  if (attachment.file){
    console.log('new',attachment);
    return uploadAttachment(attachment);
  }
});
```

Long story short I am using trix for rich text on a forum, all models and controllers are working, I am attempting to direct_upload on with a drag and drop into the editor as shown [here](https://gorails.com/episodes/trix-editor?autoplay=1)
but can't get the js right.

all other config is set direct from the [documentation](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/master/doc/direct_s3.md)

Photos are being uploaded to my aws but all are expiring in a few mins

example: https://sprout-free-forum-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/store/de6271df193b0ae16e14c3297c58c363.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAINSUNFHRJEDP6TQA%2F20181027%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181027T192116Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a4c9da3b5933ca29954dfaf11e592543c69a5a7ad1d4dcd3b70747ef0a695c38

even with my bucket set to public read

any help would be great I am lost!

This is current site [live](https://sprout-free-canada.herokuapp.com/) and [here](https://github.com/cgibsonmm/Sprout-Free) is my full git

Comment: Experiencing this issue now also. Have you fixed this @Corey Gibson?

Comment: I actually ended up implementing some ruby code that takes the return URL from AWS and parses the string and removes the part that makes it expire and not public. But thanks I will look more into this, and see if there is a better way of handling this.

Comment: That is a good solution. Have you checked my answer below? I solved my problem recently, thanks to one of the gems owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experienced this problem today also.

Also using Shrine with AWS S3, and Trix in an old rails app.

What I noticed is that the images are present in the S3 server, its just the URLs that Trix is using that does not work.

After searching some other similar questions, ran into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51197576/2561325

The answer there is from one of the maintainer of the shrine gem. All you have to do is apply the public settings in your shrine initializer in `config/initializers/shrine.rb`.

My problem is fixed now, images used by Trix editor not expiring.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help, just sent this live. I researched this for days I can't believe I did not stumble upon this!

Comment: Glad you found this useful too.